# Why does this bash script add a letter before comparing?

Tags: bash

I have a script here that includes this snippet:

```
read -p ">" DEPLOY_CONFIRM
if [ "xy" != "x$DEPLOY_CONFIRM" ] ; then
  .. snip ..
fi
```

Is adding the x before doing the comparison important? My guess is it guards against the user entering something that starts with a funny character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prefixing each variable and literal with a known constant literal `x` was done in old shell scripts while using unquoted variable to safeguard again error like `unary operator expected`.

As long as you're using quoted variables you don't need this trick of prefixing `x`.

So you could very well use this in BASH:

```
read -p ">" DEPLOY_CONFIRM
if [[ "$DEPLOY_CONFIRM" == [Yy] ]]; then
  .. snip ..
fi
```

---

**To generate this error use snippet like this:**

```
unset s
[ "y" = $s ] && echo "matched"
-bash: [: y: unary operator expected
```

And then see improved behavior with prefixing with `x`:

```
[ "xy" = x$s ] && echo "matched"
```

Comment: I think *really* old shells had a bug (feature?) where even a quoted empty string was removed, so that even `[ "y" = "$s" ]` would fail if `$s` were empty, hence the guard character to ensure that neither string was ever empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the double quotes while comparing the string which always wont give any syntax errors.

```
[ "y" = "$s" ] && echo "matched"
```